# Добавить группу Div в один большой Div с позиционированием

Tags: html, css

Имеется Div, довольно большой. Как в него мне засунуть много мелких Div'ов? Класс у мелких такой:

```
.circleDiv {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

Пытаюсь каждому мелкому Div'у добавить id, с  вот таким CSS содержимым:

```
#div_m1_4 {
    position: relative;
    left: 38px;
    top: 120px;
}
```

Но добавив много таких элементов понял обнаружил, что позиционируются они относительно предыдущего добавленного соседнего элемента (т.е. другого мелкого Div). И тут может быть проблема - если я удалю один Div в середине, то остальные тоже поплывут.

Попытался сделать позиционирование Absolut, но в этом случае позиционирование вообще от окна браузера, а не от границы родительского Div. Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте родителю `position: relative`, а вложенным `.circleDiv` `position: absolute`. Тогда не будет *"позиционирования от окна браузера"*.

PS:
Судя по вопросу, а именно:

> И тут может быть проблема - если я удалю один Div в середине, то
>   остальные тоже поплывут.

свойство `float` вам не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Позиционирование absolute всегда происходит относительно блока в котором он находится, при этом нужно задавать фиксированную ширину и высоту блоку родителю. Если вы хотите добиться последовательного размещения блоков внутри другого блока, то нужно задать свойство float.